# How to host CouchDB/PouchDB in remote server?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am creating a mobile app using Ionic 2 where I will have a bunch of data. I am exploring options for database. From my research I came to know that PouchDB is a great option. My question is:

1. Can I host PouchDB/Couch DB on a shared host ? If not, what are the options available ?
2. What other options I have for a database in a mobile app ?

Comment: This is impossibly broad. It's also not really on-topic here, since it's about server hosting, not programming. If you can narrow it down to a good question, ServerFault would be the place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Can I host PouchDB/Couch DB on a shared host ?

Probably not, but it depends on the shared host. couchdb requires erlang, and pouchdb can run server-side in nodejs. (There are also plugins to provide serialized databases to populate each client's pouchdb if you don't really need a server side database.)

> If not, what are the options available ?

There are plenty of companies hosting virtual and baremetal machines. They are usually cheaper or at least a better computing value than shared hosting, but aside from common install images, you must do any system maintenance yourself. scaleway, rackspace or digital ocean are some examples of traditional independent ones and then there are the various cloud providers..

> 2. What other options I have for a database in a mobile app ?

### **couch-protocol** (will talk to pouchdb)

- cloudant - provides a free tier hosted service, but may get expensive for larger volume.
- couchbase - the enterprise/installable version of cloudant?

### **similar JSON oriented** (likely to use similar skills)

mongodb, firebase, ...